# Laravel - CSS and JS links not working + Popper.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I just started a new project, and I want to use Bootstrap 4. I got the files, and I put them in my layouts file just like any regular HTML file, But for some reason, it doesn't work, not the CSS files and neither the JS files. I've used it with {{ asset('path/path') }} and without. It just does not work.

**Question 2**

Furthermore, For Bootstrap 4 you need popper.js and tooltip.js for dropdowns and tooltips. I installed these via npm using npm install popper.js --save. But my dropdowns still aren't working, But they do if I add the URL link in the head. I want to prevent putting the URL in the head, So why doesn't it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, buddy you need to more specific where did you put the BS4 files you got. under `public/assets/` directory?

Comment: @ManojHL I got all my CSS and JS files in the `project-name/public` folder where they should be. I think that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html your blade file is actually generating, you will be able to identify the problem. (in my case with chrome on mac this is Cmd-Alt-U).

Find the script tag and look at the path there and you will be able to identify the error. You can also use `php artisan tinker` and try out `asset('something')` to see exactly the path that little function is going to give you.